# how to use groupBy function using Dataweve in Mulesoft

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have below JSON data in Dataweave.  I'd like to groupBy products.plu then sum qty.

please see below the input and desired output. thanks

```
{
  "brandCode": "XXX",
  "storeCode": "XX100",
  "products": [
 {
    "plu": "NF0A529SWE7100L",
    "qty": 2.000
  },
  {
    "plu": "NF0A529SWE7100L",
    "qty": -1.000
  },
  {
    "plu": "NF0A529SWE7100M",
    "qty": 2.000
  }
]
  }
```

Desired Output:

```
{
  "brandCode": "XXX",
  "storeCode": "XX100",
  "products": [
 {
    "plu": "NF0A529SWE7100L",
    "qty": 1.000
  },
  {
    "plu": "NF0A529SWE7100M",
    "qty": 2.000
  }]
  }
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't see your comment. could you post again

Comment: I didn't leave any, though just a note to make sure that you verify the input and output object in a json or xml editor before publishing them here. As well if you are providing your code snippet (do provide the full snippet ), do make use of code block to render it readable .

Answer (score 0):

my code is below

```
{
      "brandCode": payload.brandCode,
      "storeCode": payload.storeCode,
      "products": 
       payload.products groupBy $.plu distinctBy $ pluck $ map{
        "plu": $.storeCode,
        "qty": (sum($.qty)),
```

but the outPut :plu is array (for example: "plu": ["NF0A529SWE7100L"])
i have to use min($.plu) ,
may i know do we have best method ?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be (making use of your code)

**Input:**

```
{
  "brandCode": "XXX",
  "storeCode": "XX100",
  "products": [
  {
    "plu": "NF0A529SWE7100L",
    "qty": 2.000
  },
  {
    "plu": "NF0A529SWE7100L",
    "qty": -1.000
  },
  {
    "plu": "NF0A529SWE7100M",
    "qty": 2.000
  }
]
}
```

**Script:**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
      "brandCode": payload.brandCode,
      "storeCode": payload.storeCode,
      "products":  payload.products groupBy $.plu pluck $ map {
           plu: $[0].plu,
           qty:sum($.qty)
      }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "brandCode": "XXX",
  "storeCode": "XX100",
  "products": [
    {
      "plu": "NF0A529SWE7100L",
      "qty": 1.000
    },
    {
      "plu": "NF0A529SWE7100M",
      "qty": 2.000
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could just use `plu: $$` inside the pluck since that is the reference to the key

Answer (score 0):

on Mule 4.3.x DW 2.3.x

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun sumProducts(data: Object): Object = (
    data update {
        case .products -> 
            data.products groupBy $.plu pluck (value, key, index) -> 
                {
                    plu: key,
                    qty: sum(value.qty default [])
                }
    }
)
---
sumProducts(payload)
```